# Issues Customizing the Ag-Grid Themes

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

How do I go about customizing the Ag-Grid themes (eg. ag-theme-material.css) in an existing Angular App?

The [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/#customizing-sass-variables) they have provided is lacking, as it doesn't explain how to perform these changes/configurations.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: did you see this example - https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-customise-theme? You need to change the Saas variables in .scss file and then import this file in your component.

Comment: @koolhuman I have seen it, but this .scss file, where does this go? Initially, I thought this was the styles.scss file in angular.

Comment: .scss file would go as an import statement in your component.ts file where you have defined your ag-grid. import './myStyles.scss';

Comment: Let me get this clear, if I need to override styles in Ag-Grid it can only be done at component level that it is nested in?

Comment: It doesn't work for me and is there clear instructions on how to achieve this? Do you have a sample program with this implemented?

Comment: are you using webpack for compiling?

Comment: Yes webpack, I made a fresh stackblitz. Can you show me what you're talking about please? https://stackblitz.com/github/alobban/Ag-Grid-Sample

Comment: check out this link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-djhzqb?file=src%2Fstyles.scss. I modified your code and imported styles.scss file in your component.ts and everything is working now.

Comment: I thought changing the font-size would change the size of the header text. Do you know which variables affect the header text? **Nevermind** found it!

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: **It works!** But the setup isn't conventional nor was there this amount detail available anywhere. Thanks @koolhuman

Comment: I will post this as an answer here and you can accept it, so this might help someone having the same question later?

Comment: Yes, there is an amount of tweaking that I need to do to make it work with my Angular app. I have to add the scripts to angular-cli.json file first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166980/discussion-between-andrew-lobban-and-koolhuman).

Comment: Agree wholly with their very poor documentation around theme customisation. We use the Enterprise version and expect Enterprise-grade documentation. We have multiple themes using CSS Custom Properties and a few AG Grid parameters cause the build to fail when set the CSS Custom Properties because of the SASS blends they use all over the place. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add ag-grid-overrides.scss file and put the saas variable you want to modify for the ag-grid theme. Full list of sass variables available can be found in this link - https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/tree/master/src/styles. Import ag-grid-overrides.scss in your component.ts file. You can still have your own .css file for each component as shown below in app.component.css file.

app.component.ts

```
import '../ag-grid-overrides.scss';
```

app.component.html

```
<ag-grid-angular class="data-grid ag-theme-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

ag-grid-overrides.scss

```
// Customize the look and feel of the grid with Sass variables
// Up-to-date list of variables is available in the source code: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/latest/src/styles/theme-fresh.scss 
$icons-path: "~ag-grid/src/styles/icons/";

// changes the border color
$border-color: #FF0000;

// Changes the font size
$font-size: 14px;

// Changes the font family
//$font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;

// Reverts the cell horizontal padding change between ag-fresh and ag-theme-fresh
//$cell-horizontal-padding: 2px;

// changes the icon color
// $icon-color: red;
//$primary-color: green;

@import '~ag-grid/src/styles/ag-grid.scss';
@import '~ag-grid/src/styles/ag-theme-fresh.scss';
```

app.component.css (**not required** as this is a custom class on ag-grid-angular)

```
.data-grid {
  width: 500px; height: 300px; margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
        "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-fresh.css",
        "styles.scss",
        "ag-grid-overrides.scss"
      ]
```

Comment: Please make sure that you don't waste a ton of time by @importing from the dist directory instead of the src directory like I just did :)

Comment: This is fine if you want to use pixels. Currently going though a world of pain making my custom vars file use rem.

Comment: How could I do that for a Vanilla JS application? I'm trying to customize a theme, but how can I attach that class on HTML id later?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it is used *"ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.1.0"* and *"ag-grid-community": "^23.1.0"* and for creating a custom theme for angular2+ application you should import to global style file(scss is in use for my case) several mixins file from ag-grid-community package and it will look like this:

```
@import '~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-grid';
@import '~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-theme-base/sass/ag-theme-base';
```

then you should include base theme with parameters set that you can override for this default theme:

```
.ag-theme-base {//should have specific name, since sizes doesn't work with custom name
  @include ag-theme-base(
    (
      foreground-color: black,
      background-color: yellow,
    )// this is parameters set object where you can ovveride ag-grid properties 
  );
}
```

List of the ag-grid parameters you can find [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-customising/#base-theme-parameters)

Also, you can extract this parameter and apply for other elements(not sure that it is a useful option but ag-grid allows this)

```
.ag-header-cell {
  background-color: ag-param(foreground-color);
  color: ag-param(background-color);
}
```

Link to documentation about ag-param function [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-customising/#ag-param).
Link to documentation regarding theme customization [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-customising/#customising-themes).

Example of usage in angular:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
  class="ag-theme-base"
  ...
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```